# Missing Stored Procedures in Linked Server view within SSMS

Tags: sql-server

Why am I unable to see Stored Procedures or functions when I open a Linked Server in SSMS? I have created the Linked Server and can see the databases, but within each database, only tables and views are shown.
The Linked Server is connected to another SQL Server instance installed on another Server, I expected to see too Programmability folder and within it the Stored procedures and functions
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation in SSMS as what I'm sure was a design choice by the developers who created it.

The reasoning likely being is because a Linked Server object can be created for a multitude of different database systems, e.g. Oracle SQL, MySQL, Snowflake database, etc. Not every database system has Procedures and Functions, or if they do, not implemented in the same way SQL Server does. Whereas Tables and Views are pretty consistent concepts and object types that exist in most modern database systems.

So to create a generic solution in SSMS, Linked Servers only expose Tables and Views under the Linked Server object node. But those other objects are still queryable (if they exist) when you write T-SQL that references them with the 4-part name. E.g: `EXEC MyLinkedServer.DatabaseName.SchemaName.spSomeStoredProcedure` is valid syntax.